# Wrap children elements of parent elements without class only if they contain text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following HTML

I am trying to wrap the child elements (label/input) where the label text says 'This one'. Basically, I need to select the full elements without class partial if they contain input text elements and not number uinput elements. One the full elements are selected, their children elements need to be completely wrapped entirely with `<div class="wrapped"></div>`

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="full">
        <label>This one</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="full partial">
        <label>Foo</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="full">
        <label>Foo</label>
        <input type="number"/>
    </div>
    <div class="full">
        <label>This one</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="full">
        <label>Foo</label>
    </div>
    <div class="full partial">
        <label>Foo</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="full partial">
        <label>Foo</label>
        <input type="number"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like this:

```
<div class="wrapped">
    <div class="full">
        <label>This one</label>
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)/[`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors to select the desired `.full` elements. Iterate over the selected elements, and wrap the children elements using a combination of the methods [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)/[`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kbo0rkyt/)

```
$('.group .full:not(.partial):has(input[type="text"])').each(function () {
    $(this).children().wrapAll('<div class="wrapped"/>');
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4bgq1hwa/)

```
$('.group input[type="text"]').closest('.full:not(.partial)').each(function () {
    $(this).children().wrapAll('<div class="wrapped"/>');
});
```

I'm not sure where approach is faster.. probably the first one.